# customize Finder 'get info' window?

Tags: cocoa, macos

OSX:
in the finder, if you select 'get info' you get a "properties window" referring to the currently selected file/folder/volume...
by default this window contains:

- spotlight comments

  General

  More Info:

  Name & Extension

  Preview

  Sharing & Permissions

does anybody know if you can add segments to this window?  say for example I wanted to add a "svn status" panel to this window...  anyone know if / how?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way to do this, and any unofficial way will be rathe difficult since Finder is a Carbon application (no dynamic objects to hijack). Additionally, the Finder has been completely rewritten for Snow Leopard, so any hack you implemented now would stop working.