# Extend the "Get Info" panel in OS X Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I want to **add a new section** to the "**Get Info**" panel in the **Finder**, but I don't know where to start. 
Everything I have found about "[App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/)" seems to refer to adding extensions to apps/applications, not the finder.

There are [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165599/customize-finder-get-info-window) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500983/how-to-get-the-get-info-pane-in-finder-programmingly-objective-c) questions that have been asked, but the newest one is two years old and was never answered.

I'll *gladly* accept examples in any language, or a pointer to docs on how to do this; I haven't been able to find anything.

[image: get info]

Comment: Dropbox/GDrive have know how how to inject code into Finder (this code stopped working on El Cap). Start by looking there and then consider if you can do what they did. Mind that even if you succeed it will never go to Mac App Store, can break anytime, works differently under every OS X and it has zero value to the user.

Comment: What led you to believe that this was possible?

Comment: I _thought_ I had seen something do this, years ago, but I must be mis-remembering.

Comment: I know you can add context-menu items, I'll just have to do that and have it launch my own custom thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. At least not using publics APIs provided by Apple. You may be able to do something with techniques like SIMBL, but that's not even sure, and it requires a solid knowledge of the Mac OS X environment.

If you are new to OS X development, this is probably not the best place to start...

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to take another approach.