# How do I put more info into Finder's Get Info panel for my app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist

In our product, the build number of the app is very important information. We don't want to put this in the app bundle's name, but we do want it to show up in Finder's Get Info panel for our `.app`. Currently, the version string (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) shows just fine, but the build number (`CFBundleVersion`) doesn't show at all.

**How do I show non-predetermined information in the Get Info dialog for my app?**

Comment: Do you mean the Finder's Get Info panel, or your app's About panel?

Comment: @Ssswift I mean Finder's Get Info panel. Our app has no main window, so no About panel.

Comment: Maybe?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165599/customize-finder-get-info-window#comment1089339_1218132

Comment: @Ssswift hopefully not, seeing how old that is.